# Can bool/filter query automatically ignore stopwords in the query?

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene

I have a custom analyzer that ignores common words like "the","a","an","on":

```
  {
    "analysis": {
      "filter": {
        "my_stopwords": {
          "type": "stop",
          "stopwords": [
            "the",
            "a",
            "an",
            "on"
          ]
        }
      },
      "analyzer": {
        "customAnalyzer": {
          "type": "custom",
          "tokenizer": "standard",
          "filter": [
            "lowercase",
            "my_stopwords"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Here's a field called "thisField" that uses the customAnalyzer which stores short text:

```
"thisField": {
            "type": "text",
            "norms": false,
            "analyzer": "customAnalyzer"
 }
```

Some example documents:

```
[  
   {
      id:1,
      thisField:"the cat is on the table"
   },
   {
      id:2,
      thisField:"expensive table"
   }
]
```

My filtered query requires a word-by-word search for "on table" in the `thisField`. I cannot turn up any results with the following query. I figure out that it's because of the inclusion of "on" in the query.  **Is there any settings in elasticsearch that makes filtered queries automatically ignore any of the stopwords in the query?**

```
"query": {
  "bool": {
    "filter": {
      "bool": {
        "must": [
          {
            "term": {
              "thisField": "on"
            }
          },
          {
            "term": {
              "thisField": "table"
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Why not use a phrase query here like the following? Or do you specifically need a filtered query?
GET /_search
{
    "query": {
        "match_phrase" : {
            "message" : {
                "query" : "on the table",
                "analyzer" : "customAnalyzer"
            }
        }
    }
}

Comment: Since you know the stop words beforehand, the logic that creates your `bool/must` query should know it, too and not include a `term` query for a  stop word.